# QML ListView and ListModel index

Tags: listview, indexing, qml

I have a little problem with ListModel and ListView, in particular concerning the move function of ListModel. I will show you code snippets from the DynamicList example included in the SDK with some modifications just to debug it:
Code:

```
  Item {     
   property alias nameText:  nameTextBox.text
        id: delegateItem
        width: listView.width; height: 55
        clip: true
        Row {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            spacing: 10
            Column {
                Image {
                    source: "content/pics/arrow-up.png"  
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent;

                        onClicked: {

                            var voice
                            var nameInModel
                            var nameInView

                            voice = listView.contentItem.children[1]
                            nameInModel = fruitModel.get(1).name

                            nameInView = voice.nameText

                            console.log("name before move in model at 1: "+nameInModel)
                            console.log("name before move in list at 1: "+nameInView)

                             fruitModel.move(index, index-1, 1)

                            voice = listView.contentItem.children[1]

                            nameInView = voice.nameText

                            nameInModel = fruitModel.get(1).name
                            console.log("name after move in model at 1: "+nameInModel)
                            console.log("name after move in list at 1: "+nameInView)

                        }
                    }
                }
....
```

So, when the image "content/pics/arrow-up.png" is clicked, one item in the model is moved up by one position, now, in the example there are four items in order: "Apple"-"Banana"-"Cumqat"-"Durian" and this is the result of consol.log if I click "up" on the "Banana" moving that item to the first position:

name before move in model at 1: Banana
name before move in list at 1: Apple
name after move in model at 1: Apple
name after move in list at 1: Apple

This is what happens if I click on Apple (that now is in the 2nd place) to moving it to the 1st position:

name before move in model at 1: Apple
name before move in list at 1: Apple
name after move in model at 1: Banana
name after move in list at 1: Apple

So, first of all it is evident that the first index of ListModel is 0 while the first index of ListView is 1, then it is evident that items in the model have been moved but items in the list have not.
Now, this is my problem: Imagine that "name" is the text of a TextEdit, so the the ListView delegate includes a TextEdit and it can be edited by the user. If I want to take that text I know that I can do this:
Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= myListView.count; i++){
     myItem= myListView.contentItem.children[i]
     myName = myListView.name
```

But here is the problem, in my ListView there is also the possibility to move the items by using the move function of ListModel but if I move items and I use the previous cycle to take the "name" nothing seems to change (exactly as in the DynamicList example).
On the other hand, if I take the "name" by using:

```
  myName= myListModel.get(i).name
```

then, nothing seems to change when I modify the text in the TextEdit and I try to take the "name",

So, what I have to do to obtain a ListView with TextEdit and with the possibility to move itemsof which I can record any changment?

I hope I have been clear, Thank you very much,
Giammarco

Answer (score 6):

You are doing it wrong, just use this :

```
import QtQuick 2.0;

Rectangle {
    width: 400;
    height: 300;

    ListView {
        id: listTest;
        clip: true;
        currentIndex: -1;
        model: ListModel {
            id: modelTest;

            ListElement { name: "Banana"; }
            ListElement { name: "Apple";  }
            ListElement { name: "Orange"; }
            ListElement { name: "Pear";   }
        }
        delegate: Item {
            id: item;
            height: 60;
            anchors {
                left: parent.left;
                right: parent.right;
            }

            property bool isCurrent : (model.index === listTest.currentIndex);
            onIsCurrentChanged: {
                if (isCurrent) {
                    input.forceActiveFocus ();
                }
                else {
                    input.focus = false;
                }
            }

            Text {
                id: label;
                font.pixelSize: 14;
                text: model.name;
                visible: !item.isCurrent;
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left;
                    right: btnUp.left;
                    margins: 20;
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter;
                }
            }
            TextInput {
                id: input;
                text: model.name;
                visible: item.isCurrent;
                onTextChanged: { modelTest.setProperty (model.index, "name", text); }
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left;
                    right: btnUp.left;
                    margins: 20;
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter;
                }

                Rectangle {
                    z: -1;
                    radius: 5;
                    antialiasing: true;
                    border {
                        width: 1;
                        color: "blue";
                    }
                    anchors {
                        fill: parent;
                        margins: -5;
                    }
                }
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: clicker;
                anchors.fill: parent;
                visible: !item.isCurrent;
                onClicked: { listTest.currentIndex = model.index; }
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: btnUp;
                width: height;
                anchors {
                    top: parent.top;
                    right: parent.right;
                    bottom: parent.verticalCenter;
                }
                onClicked: {
                    if (model.index > 0) {
                        modelTest.move (model.index, model.index -1, 1);
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    text: "V";
                    color: "gray";
                    rotation: -180;
                    anchors.centerIn: parent;
                }
            }
            MouseArea {
                id: btnDown;
                width: height;
                anchors {
                    top: parent.verticalCenter;
                    right: parent.right;
                    bottom: parent.bottom;
                }
                onClicked: {
                    if (model.index < modelTest.count -1) {
                        modelTest.move (model.index, model.index +1, 1);
                    }
                }

                Text {
                    text: "V";
                    color: "gray";
                    anchors.centerIn: parent;
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                height: 1;
                color: "lightgray";
                anchors {
                    left: parent.left;
                    right: parent.right;
                    bottom: parent.bottom;
                }
            }
        }
        anchors.fill: parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, line 33 `input = false;` gives an error about `input` not being an lvalue. I don't yet understand what that line is doing or what it should be.